# sqlite.Interop.dll could not find assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, sqlite, compatibility, .net-assembly

I have devloped a visual studio wpf application in which I am using sqlite as the database, now when I try to deploy the application on other machine(32 bit Windows 7) I get a could not load the assembly module sqlite.Interop.dll

I tried adding the the particular dll file with properties set to Content and Copy Always, and checked on the client system  sqlite.interop.dll exist in the same directory as the application exe. I cant understand the reason because the application installs and works perfectly fine on my system (32 bit Windows XP).

I created the setup project using the setup tools i Visual Studio 2010 by adding project output to application folder..This is the first time I am doing deployment so I am a bit at my wits end...any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Install Sqlite For Ado.Net and add reference from GAC http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand...install where?? on my PC or on client's machine??, I have already installed it in my PC

Comment: downloaded and installed on the client machine still not working, Can it be because of the second thing,i.e Add reference from GAC???...you mean adding the references of .net provider from GAC during development of the project or during the devlopment of Setup project??

Comment: try registering the dll. In setup you can find a property for dll registration having default value Do Not Register. or manually you can do it regsvr32 -i path_of_dll

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having a similar issue and cannot deploy my application, which has a third party dll, successfully.